# Nodejs array object not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am getting a data from mongoose database. And It have some array which have ids which data I need to get from other api. All is working but when I change the object of array like this in for loop `team[i].teamPlayersDetails = playerss;` Its not changing I can even see playerss have data but its not changing the team.

```
const getAllTeams = async (req, res) => {
    let team = await Team.find();
    var userids = [];
    var usersdata = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < team[i].teamPlayers.length; j++) {
            userids.push(team[i].teamPlayers[j])
        }
    }
    var data = {
        'ids': userids
    }

    await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/auth/getMultipleUserByUserID`, data)
        .then(async function (response) {
            usersdata = response.data.data
        });

    for (let i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
        playerss = [];

        team[i].teamPlayers.forEach(player_id => {
            playerss.push(usersdata.find(p => p.userID === player_id.toString()))
            team[i].teamPlayersDetails = playerss;
        })
    }

    if (!team) {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "user not found", success: false })
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "success", success: true, data: team })
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it is not changing*? Do you mean changes are not reflected in database?

Comment: use lean and then check `let team = await Team.find().lean();` I hope this will work

Comment: @MominRaza yeah it's working with lean :D but why. ?

Comment: By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. Documents are much heavier than vanilla JavaScript objects because they have a lot of internal states for change tracking. Enabling the lean option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the simple data in JS. after using lean you cannot update an object and then save ( you cannot use `teams.save()` ). Please give my comment up vote if its help you thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lean and then check

```
let team = await Team.find().lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic has a flaw. You are updating the `team[I].teamPlayersDetails` over each `player_id` iterated upon. You should be only performing the update when all `player_id`s have been iterated.

You are better using the `map` operator function to transform the `player_id`s to their respective details hence no need for the intermediary `playerss` array.

If you would like your changes to be reflected in the database, you should perform the update explicitly using `updateOne` or `updateMany` collection methods.

```
const getAllTeams = async (req, res) => {
    let team = await Team.find();
    const userids = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < team[i].teamPlayers.length; j++) {
            userids.push(team[i].teamPlayers[j]);
        }
    }

    const usersResponse = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/auth/getMultipleUserByUserID`, { 'ids': userids });
    const usersdata = usersResponse.data.data;

    for (let i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
        const teamPlayersDetails = team[i].teamPlayers.map(player_id => usersdata.find(p => p.userID === player_id.toString()));
        await Team.updateOne({ _id: team[I]._id.toString() }, { $set: { teamPlayersDetails } });
    }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: But by this we are saving details in teamPlayersDetails but team is still not updating ? Mean we need to save data in team[i].teamPlayers

Answer (score -1):

Instead of forEach i suggest you to use classic for loop

Comment: On what do you base your SUGGESTION?